# taskhostw.exe crashing several times a minute with InputLocaleManager.dll as fault module

Tags: windows-10, crash, dll

A few days ago I've noticed increased disk activity on my Windows 10 Home PC so I've checked resource monitor and found out there were quite a few Werfault.exe processes, writing reports. Examining the reports shows that taskhostw.exe is crashing and InputLocaleManager.dll is the faulty module. The same error can be seen in Event viewer. This happens about every 8 seconds.

Content of report.wer:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131267481929766029
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131267481931641077
ReportIdentifier=8c97b0fd-c707-11e6-bf2d-ac220b19dec4
IntegratorReportIdentifier=3ded9dee-26d2-46d7-8b33-db78a12a9e81
NsAppName=taskhostw.exe
AppSessionGuid=000018e4-0001-0015-06cd-d24e145bd201
TargetAppId=W:0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000!00009cc394e9f9aef58f7bdb90b8b19559ab6605cb64!taskhostw.exe
TargetAppVer=2016//07//16:02:23:11!1bd11!taskhostw.exe
BootId=4294967295
Response.BucketId=5d8b0d44ad7bdef1b2697bf5feff2eca
Response.BucketTable=4
Response.LegacyBucketId=120659891909
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=taskhostw.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=10.0.14393.0
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=57899a8f
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=InputLocaleManager.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=10.0.14393.576
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=584a7724
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=0000000000007134
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.14393.2.0.0.768.101
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1051
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=d3ba
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=d3bac9e4524de6ab61af7cbf9ea8cd9f
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=5987
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=5987e39f73861b03c6c8fcbfb4e87a05
UI[2]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskhostw.exe
UI[3]=Host Process for Windows Tasks has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskhostw.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\imm32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\MsCtfMonitor.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSUTB.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\InputService.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\EditBufferTestHook.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\CoreUIComponents.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\CoreMessaging.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\TextInputFramework.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\advapi32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\MTFServer.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\InputLocaleManager.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Host Process for Windows Tasks
AppPath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\taskhostw.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=D0666F5CFC65B757C87E8591F77E2C56
MetadataHash=-1491127876
```

I've tried running sfc /scannow, which didn't find any problems, I have even renamed InputLocaleManager.dll (in safe mode) and then ran sfc /scannow which found it missing and replaced the file, I did check for virus/malware infection with Windows defender and Malwarebytes but none of those changed anything.

Another strange thing is, that I cannot type into Windows search box (after pressing Win-S the box opens, cursor blinks, but no keypress is echoed). The same applies to Settings app. Everywhere else the keyboard works normally, except for a small stutter every 8 seconds or so, when the process crashes.

Anybody has an idea, what else can I try or where to look to solve this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem, man? I have exactly the same.

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but I got rid of it by doing restore from some earlier date. I never found out what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Windows service "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service" and reboot the computer.